# Find percent diff and diff with consecutive but odd number of dates

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, percentage

I have a dataset, df, where I wish to find the percent diff and diff. I wish to look at the earliest date and compare this value to the next date:

```
 id    date         value

 1     11/01/2020   10
 2     11/01/2020   5
 1     10/01/2020   20
 2     10/01/2020   30
 1     09/01/2020   15
 2     09/01/2020   10
 3     11/01/2020   5
```

***Desired output***

```
  id    date          diff   percent


  1     10/01/2020    5       33                 
  1     11/01/2020   -10     -50
  2     10/01/2020    20      200               
  2     11/01/2020   -25   -83.33
  3     11/01/2020     0       0
```

I am wanting to look at one group at a time and compare the previous value to the next value and find the percent increase and diff.

***For example***,

***ID 1, from 09/01/2020 to 10/01/2020*** : goes from ***15 to 20***,
giving a difference of ***5***
***percent difference is 33%***

***from 10/01/2020  to 11/01/2020:*** goes from ***20 to 10,***
***difference of ***-10*** and a ***50% percent difference.******

This what I am doing:

```
a['date'] = pd.to_datetime(a['date'])
grouped = a.sort_values('date').groupby(['id'])

output = pd.DataFrame({
'date': grouped['date'].agg(lambda x: x.iloc[-1]).values,
'diff': grouped['value'].agg(lambda x: x.diff().fillna(0).iloc[-1]).values,
'percentdiff': grouped['value'].agg(lambda x: x.pct_change().fillna(0).iloc[-1] * 100).values,
'type': grouped['id'].agg(lambda x: x.iloc[0]).values
})
```

However, I notice that some values are missing, as this is my output:

[image]

*Is it possible to achieve my desired output?*
Perhaps a loop would have to be implemented to refer back to the previous date row and compare to the next?

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way around it, assuming I get your logic right :

The idea is to use `shift` for each group to calculate the difference and percentage,

```
result = (df.sort_values(["id", "date", "value"])
                  # use this later to drop the first row per group
                  # if number is greater than 1, else leave as-is
          .assign(counter=lambda x: x.groupby("id").date.transform("size"),
                  date_shift=lambda x: x.groupby(["id"]).date.shift(1),
                  value_shift=lambda x: x.groupby("id").value.shift(1),
                  diff=lambda x: x.value - x.value_shift,
                  percent=lambda x: x["diff"].div(x.value_shift).mul(100).round(2))
           # here is where the counter column becomes useful
           # drop rows where date_shift is null and counter is > 1
           # this way if number of rows in the group is just one it is kept, 
           # if greater than one, the first row is dropped, 
           # as the first row would have nulls due to the `shift` method.
          .query("not (date_shift.isna() and counter>1)")
          .loc[:, ["id", "date", "diff", "percent"]]
          .fillna(0))

result



   id   date        diff    percent
2   1   10/01/2020   5.0     33.33
0   1   11/01/2020  -10.0   -50.00
3   2   10/01/2020   20.0    200.00
1   2   11/01/2020  -25.0   -83.33
6   3   11/01/2020   0.0     0.00
```

Comment: Ah, ok I wasn’t exactly sure how to implement this! Thank you, let me try this now! - so it wouldn’t matter if there is an off set of groups when using shift, I presume?

Comment: Really helpful, I will keep researching this. Thank you

Comment: Hi @Sammywemmy , for some reason when I add my large dataset column names: 'POD', 'Date', 'Size', I keep getting this error: AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'date' Trying to figure this out. Any suggestion?

Comment: My full dataset has Date as the column name. Maybe I am not entering something correctly. The sample dataset works fine

Comment: is there a way to include the start and end date for the output? I may create a new post and am researching this now